# How expensive are repeated import calls in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

I want to put an import inside a function, like so:

```
def a():
  import x
  ...
```

This is because the module is just a collection of miscellaneous functions, and the user might not want to use the `a` function at all. But I don't want `a` to become slow because of the repeated, redundant `import` calls.

Comment: Imports are cached in Python by default.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know that, but I am specifically asking how expensive a 'cached" import is. It might still be expensive.

Comment: It's a dictionary lookup. Try timing it.